# Is there any way to optimize the performance of a Mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

I have a collection in prod with 200k documents. I am trying to use the below query to generate a report based on 200k documents.

Performance is very slow and also I am unable to export the document to CSV format.

Is there any way we can improve the performance?

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {"$match":
        {'msgs.crtDtTm':
            { $gt: '1554163199000',$lt: '1556668799000'}
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$msgs"},
    {"$group":
        { "_id":
            {"webGuId":"$webGuId",
             "fstNme":"$fstNme",
             "lstNme":"$lstNme",
             "dob":"$dob",
             "mcId":"$mcId",
             "status":"$msgs.stts"
            },
            "count": {"$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { "$sort" : { "webGuId" : 1 } }
])
```

Comment: Have you looked at supporting your query with an [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the documents from this collection? And the number of documents returned by `db.getCollection('test').count({'msgs.crtDtTm':{ $gt: '1554163199000',$lt: '1556668799000'}})`? And finally the usual size of the array `msg`.